# npm gray-matter is not working with latest nextjs and node versions

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using latest nextjs version. I have to display markdown blogs using gray-matter but seems like example given on official documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter is also not working.
Including my files in this code

Package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "clsx": "1.2.1",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "remark": "^14.0.2",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.2",
    "styled-components": "6.0.0-beta.2",
    "styled-jsx": "5.1.0",
    "use-count-up": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.0.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "latest",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
```

File where I am reading the blogs.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { remark } from 'remark'
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import remarkHtml from 'remark-html'

// const matter = require('gray-matter');

export function getAllPosts() {
  const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), '/blogs/HFTs')
  const filenames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)

  return filenames.map(filename => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), '/blogs/HFTs', filename), 'utf8')
   
    // get frontmatter
    const { data, content } = matter(file)
    console.log(matter('---\ntitle: Front Matter\n---\nThis is content.'));

    // get slug from filename
    const slug = filename.replace(/\.mdx$/, '')

    // return combined frontmatter and slug; build permalink
    return {
      ...data,
      permalink: `/HFTs/${slug}`,
      slug,
    }
  })
}
```

the result of the official example is also not working.

```js
console.log(grayMatter('---\ntitle: Front Matter\n---\nThis is content.'));
// is printing
{
  content: '---\ntitle: Front Matter\n---\nThis is content.',
  data: {},
  isEmpty: false,
  excerpt: '',
  orig: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 0a 74 69 74 6c 65 3a 20 46 72 6f 6e 74 20 4d 61 74 74 65 72 0a 2d 2d 2d 0a 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2e>
}
```

Data is empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using [Turbopack](https://turbo.build/). Turbopack is still in experimental mode and does not support mdx right now.
Fixed the problem by removing Turbopack from my project.

Comment: This is still the case for the lastest template from vercel. Currently working with blog-starter and it is not working. Node version `18.19.0`.